# Angular, dynamically get component ref, on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component which can contain 1 of 10 different child components, based on some condition.

```
<div *ngIf="type === 1">
    <component_1></component_1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="type === 2">
    <component_2></component_2>
</div>

<div *ngIf="type === 3">
    <component_3></component_3>
</div>
...
```

In that component I need method which will return proper child component reference in any moment (on button click for example).

```
getComponentRef() {
  switch (this.type) {
     case 1: {
       // return component_1 ref;
       break;
     }
     case 2: {
       // return component_2 ref;
       break;
     }
     case 3: {
       // return component_3 ref;
       break;
     }
     ...
   }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you pass the reference already to the click handler?

Comment: Click handler will come from parent component. Parent component does not know which component is rendered.

Comment: Make those components to implement a common interface; use `@ViewChildren` with that interface type, then on your switch case, just switch for the component type. This would be the most clever way to make it, so that if those components share common behaviors, you can handle actions direcly using the interface.

Comment: I have 3 types of component, unfortunately they does not have any common features.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:-

1. `parent.component.html`

   ```
   <div *ngIf="type === 1">
       <component_1 (emittedEvent)="setActiveChildTab($event)"></component_1>
   </div>

   <div *ngIf="type === 2">
       <component_2 (emittedEvent)="setActiveChildTab($event)"></component_2>
   </div>

   <div *ngIf="type === 3">
       <component_3 (emittedEvent)="setActiveChildTab($event)"></component_3>
   </div>
   ...
   ```
2. `parent.component.ts` create a variable to store the reference of child e.g. `activeTab: string`

   ```
   setActiveChildTab(activeTab: string) {
       this.activeTab = activeTab;
   }
   ```
3. In every `child.component.ts` create a variable to emit the active tab e.g.
   `@Output() emittedEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()`.

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
       this.emittedEvent.emit('Child1');
   }
   ```

Let me know if it works or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have already type value in `ngIf`. You can use it.

2) You need to create one `EventEmitter` in common Service file.

With that you can emit the flag from all the component's `ngOnInit()` and subscribe in component.

3) You can manage via cookie also.

4) Manage via parent-child data transfer also.

Comment: I am using loop to render this components. Like a list of components and any component can be different type.
Is there any way to do it simple, to get child component ref dynamically exactly as I  need ?

Comment: Yes , you can go with 2nd option. I'm using that one for this type of cases and it works fine for me. I hope it will helpful to you also.

Comment: I fixed this problem with adding input parameter 'componentRef' to every child component and on ngOnInit set 'this' of current component to 'componentRef'. In that case parent component will have proper child component reference.
You did not put any code here and I did not understand very well some of your choices, but you gave me idea, thanks :).
I can post my answer here also.